# Где находятся данные PlayerPrefs в проекте?

Tags: unity3d

По какому пути можно найти значения `PlayerPrefs` в проекте?

Comment: Если вы используете `PlayerPrefs` для сохранения настроек редактора - это плохо, для этого есть [EditorPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html).

Answer (score 1):

[PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) никак не привязан к проекту/билду, записи хранятся в разных местах на разных ОС:

> **macOS**, PlayerPrefs are stored in `~/Library/Preferences folder`

> **Windows**, PlayerPrefs are stored in the *registry* under
> `HKCU\Software\[company name]\[product name]`

> **Linux**, PlayerPrefs can be found in
> `~/.config/unity3d/[CompanyName]/[ProductName]`

> **Windows Store Apps**, Player Prefs can be found in
> `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\[ProductPackageId]>\LocalState\playerprefs.dat`

> **Windows Phone 8**, Player Prefs can be found in application's local
> folder

> **Android**, data is stored (persisted) on the device. The data is saved in
> SharedPreferences. C#/JavaScript, Android Java and Native code can all
> access the PlayerPrefs data. The PlayerPrefs data is *physically* stored
> in `/data/data/pkg-name/shared_prefs/pkg-name.xml`

> **WebGL**, PlayerPrefs are stored using the browser's IndexedDB API

> **iOS**, PlayerPrefs are stored in `/Library/Preferences/[bundle identifier].plist`

**P.S.**
Проект в редакторе будет хранить `PlayerPrefs` так, словно он делает это в билде.

Comment: Нет это не то, это в уже готовом билде. Вот правильный ответ https://unity3dschool.ru/sohranenie-i-zagruzka-dannyh-v-unity-igre.html

Comment: @БулатКирамов вы почитайте, что в `Windows` написано про регистр, не вижу различий в этом ответе и ссылкой, что вы скинули.